# CodeIgniter Printing data with relationship

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm looking at the CodeIgniter Documentation and only find a way to get an entire table, I'm looking for a way to get the `UserID` and the `CourseTitle` column in a row from diffferent but related tables.

I have this tables:

**User_table**

```
UserID | CourseID
```

`CourseID` here is the foreign key

**Course_table**

```
CourseID | CourseTitle
```

The `CourseID` here is the primary key

**Controller:**

```
public function index(){     
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->user_Call();
    $data['title'] = 'News archive';
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function user_Call(){
   $query = $this->db->get('news');    
   $query = $this->db->get('news');
   return $query->result_array();    
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
    <div id="main">
        <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at below function i have made sample for you. Try it.

```
public function user_Call()
{
   $this->db->select('u.UserID,c.CourseTitle', false);
   $this->db->from('User_table AS u');
   $this->db->join('Course_table AS c', 'c.CourseID = u.CourseID');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result_array();    
}
```

Comment: I'm having an Error Number: 1066
Not unique table/alias: 'User_table'. I checked my table name and my database I'm sure it's the right name.

Comment: This time it's Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'c.CourseTitle' in 'field list', it seems like the select part is not working right. Maybe we should put the alias on top before using it in the select? is that possible?

Comment: Hey Man I get it now, I think I'll play around it some more just to make sure.